# force lifecycle prerequisite for maven plugin execution?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin

I use the maven-properties-plugin during the initialization phase to read in a bunch of properties from a properties file.

I also have the jetty plugin configured to set a couple of the project properties - including those read in above - as system properties to jetty.

If I run the result as

```
mvn initialize jetty:run-war
```

it works.

If I just say

```
mvn jetty:run-war
```

it fails. How can I force a goal specified on the command line to run in a lifecycle that includes the initialization phase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I just say `mvn jetty:run-war` it fails.

That's not what I'm experiencing. If you look at the documentation of the [`jetty:run-war`](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/maven-plugin/run-war-mojo.html) goal, you'll see that it:

> Invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase `package` prior to executing itself.

So all the phases preceding `package` plus the `package` itself are run and, consequently, the plugins bound to them. And indeed, with the following POM:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>q2488581</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>q2488581 Maven Webapp</name>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.10</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <files>
                <file>etc/config/dev.properties</file>
              </files>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Running `mvn jetty:run-war` produces the following output:

```
$ mvn jetty:run-war
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building q2488581 - Maven Webapp
[INFO]    task-segment: [jetty:run-war]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Preparing jetty:run-war
[INFO] [properties:read-project-properties {execution: default}]
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/q2488581/src/test/resources
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] [surefire:test {execution: default-test}]
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] [war:war {execution: default-war}]
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp[q2488581] in [/home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/q2488581/target/q2488581]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources[/home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/q2488581/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in[76 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/q2488581/target/q2488581.war
[INFO] [jetty:run-war {execution: default-cli}]
...
```

As we can see, `properties:read-project-properties` is invoked during the `initialize` phase (before `process-resources` to which `resources:resources` is bound) as expected.

In other words, I cannot reproduce your problem (or maybe you should be more specific).

Comment: Your example is almost exactly what I was trying to do, and it wasn't working. I am at a loss.

I wound up mooting the problem by making changes to the application context so that it didn't have to be a system property anymore and ripped it all out.

Answer (score 1):

Following works for me. Hope this helps.
file: pom.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- mvn -Plocal -->
        <id>local</id>
        <build>
            <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run-war</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```